# Memoizing functions in a hash table

Tags: reference, ocaml, memoization

I must complete an exercise in which

I write a function **memo : (('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b) -> stats -> 'a -> 'b.** The function memo takes as input a function f (the function we want to memoize), a record of type stats (its type declaration is given below) to keep track of how often we access the local store and how many entries we add, and returns a function of type 'a -> 'b.

When this function is called with an input of type 'a, it will run f, memoize intermediate results, and return as a final result a value of type 'b. It will also update the values in its stats record accordingly. For example, to create a memoizing function that sums up numbers up to x, we have memo (fun g x -> if x=0 then 0 else x + g(x-1)) stats

The record type stats has two fields:

entries: the number of results that have been memoized

lkp: the number of times a memoized result has been found in the store instead of executing the function

Note the type of the given function f: it in itself requires another function as argument. Specifically, the function g passed to f will be the function that f will call in its recursive case.

The issue I am having is that the number of lookups for me is always off by 1 or 2. If anyone could clarify why this is happening or give me a hint, I'd appreciate it. Below is my attempt, which computes the correct values for the function calls and the correct number of entries. Hopefully the code below will make it clearer:

```
type stats =
  { entries : int ref;
    lkp : int ref }

let memo (f: (('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b)) (stats: stats) : ('a -> 'b) =

  let map = Hashtbl.create 1000 in
  let rec g x =
    match Hashtbl.find_opt map x with
    | None -> let result = f (g) x in Hashtbl.add map x result ; stats.entries := !(stats.entries) + 1 ; result
    | Some v -> stats.lkp := !(stats.lkp)+ 1 ; v 
  in stats.entries := !(stats.entries) + 1 ; f g
```

Comment: Please don't modify the question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's deobfuscate your code:

```
type stats = {
  entries : int ref;
  lkp : int ref
}

let memo (f: (('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b)) (stats: stats) : ('a -> 'b) =
  let map = Hashtbl.create 1000 in
  let rec g x =
    match Hashtbl.find_opt map x with
    | None ->
      let result = f (g) x in
      Hashtbl.add map x result;
      incr stats.entries;
      result
    | Some v ->
      incr stats.lkp;
      v in
  incr stats.entries;
  f g
```

Now, we can easily see that in case if we have a cache miss (the `None` branch), we increment the number of entries (looks correct) but not the number of lookups (looks suspicious, I would still count this as a lookup, unless by lookup you mean a cache hit). When we have a cache hit (the `Some` branch), we increment the number of lookups. So far so good. We also can see that for some reason we increment the number of entries unconditionally when we call `memo`. That totally looks odd, we do not add any entries here. Most likely it is some leftover code.

I hope the rest is clear. The main take away is that you should try to write programs that are syntactically easy to digest. Do not afraid to use the Enter button on your keyboard, do not try to make too much at once. Also, try to use an IDE (vscode, emacs, vim) that supports automatic indentation. It will save you from nasty surprises.

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot better than what I had. I unconditionally increment stats.entries there because for some reason that seems to give me the correct number of entries when the function call is done, although I agree that it doesn't make sense. This along with my number of lookups being 1 or 2 greater than they should be makes me think some cases are not being cached properly, but I am not sure.

Comment: albeit the missing `incr stats.lkp` in the miss case (the None branch) I don't see any more issues with your code and when I run it I get numbers that I expect.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the style tips anyway. I managed to fix my issue by replacing "f g" with just "g" in the last line, and also deleting that superfluous increment operation on the last line. I actually thought in this case replacing f g with g would not make a difference, but surprisingly it did

Comment: @JeffreyScofield, I think you posted a comment to a wrong posting :)

Comment: (The comment was OK  but the code has been corrected now.)

Comment: I didn't correct anything) I mean that the comment is for the OP posting, not to my answer.